# Scala JsObject to nested class

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have this scenario im getting a list of  Facebook feed(facebook api)  to a list of json objects.
Than i want to deserialize    to a list of class object.

First question is ,which data structure  will be best  practices ? (cass class,tratis or regular class)

This is how i did it  , i created a list of **Comments** in the **Post**  case class

```
case class Post(id: String, fromId: String, fromName: String, message: String, fullUrl:     String, createdTime: String, updateTime: String ,List[Comment]) {   
 }
  case class Comment(id: String, fromId: String, fromName: String, message: String, creationTime: String, likeCount: Int)
```

Then im mapping it like that

```
 implicit val post = (
(__ \ "id").read[String] and
  (__ \ "from").\("id").read[String] and
  (__ \ "from").\("name").read[String]  and
  (__ \ "message").read[String]  and
  (__ \ "actions").\\("link").read[String]  and
  (__ \ "created_time").read[String]  and
  (__ \ "updated_time").read[String]
  )(Post)
```

The second question is how can i map  the list ??

thanks,

miki

Answer (score 1):

1. Case classes looks good in this case.
2. You need to define the same implicit reader for comments and then change you reader for posts something like that:

   ```
   implicit val post = 2
   (__ \ "id").read[String] and
     (__ \ "from").\("id").read[String] and
     (__ \ "from").\("name").read[String]  and
     (__ \ "message").read[String]  and
     (__ \ "actions").\\("link").read[String]  and
     (__ \ "created_time").read[String]  and
     (__ \ "updated_time").read[String] and
     (__ \ "comments").reads[List[Comment]]
   )(Post)
   ```